# Xna racing game on multi monitor setup or alternatives via C#

Tags: c#, xna, multiple-monitors, racing

I'm developing a car game where a person uses a wheel on a pc connected to two projectors. One projector should show the front view and the other the view from the back of the car. The object of the game is to park the car in a parking place. I decided to go with XNA and Racing game starter kit. I don't know how to render two cameras on different monitors.

Please advise how to split render in XNA with code and I hope someone out there has experience with the starter kit.

ps i would accept other solutions like wpf3d if they can manage good fps. I don't need a complex scene. A couple of buildings. Sprite background and two cars to park between them.

tnx
v.

Comment: Not sure if it is a complete answer, but maybe look [here](http://glassarrow.blogspot.com/2009/02/xna-c-how-to-create-full-screen.html)

Comment: i found that link over google but not good enough. no code and he overrides classes (i'm not that good in xna)

Comment: I think that you have to create two rendertargets, for both screens, then render each camera to own rendertargets, then just render rendertargets as images. http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series3/Render_to_texture.php to some reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [link](http://forums.xna.com/forums/p/10227/53871.aspx) that links to this [.zip](http://aj.uwcs.co.uk/XNA/Samples/SimpleAnimationSample_MultiMonitor.zip) . It uses a Second Windows form with `device.Present(window2.Handle);`

If anybody needs to modify the racing kit it's in the GameScreen.cs where i used manual `present() & present(handle)`